# Help me write very simple BASH script?

Tags: bash

I am wishing to automate adding SFTP users. My commands required are the following, taking for example adding the user 'jason':

```
useradd jason
passwd jason
mkdir /home/jason
chown root:jason /home/jason
chmod 775 /home/jason
usermod -d /home/jason jason
usermod -a -G sftp jason
mount --bind /srv/ftp/~jason /home/jason
```

How may I replace each name with a variable for BASH, and have it ask for password at the beginning so it may plug it in where it is required?

I will try to learn to do this on my own, my mental capacity is very limited right now..

Comment: Isn't `useradd` able to perform most of the tasks you are listing?

Comment: I think so - I will try to modify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter user: " user
read -s -p "Enter password: " pass

useradd "$user"
passwd --stdin "$user" <<<"$pass"
mkdir /home/"$user"
chown root:"$user" /home/"$user"
chmod 775 /home/"$user"
usermod -d /home/"$user" "$user"
usermod -a -G sftp "$user"
mount --bind /srv/ftp/~"$user" /home/"$user"
```

Note that if your version of `passwd` doesn't support the `--stdin` option, you're going to need to use something like `expect` or `autoexpect`

Comment: It seems --stdin is not an option, how may I perform expect? Thank your soul for helping me.

Comment: Ah - I read somewhere you can use `echo username:password | chpasswd`, I'll try.

Comment: @Tim looks like a good alternative. In your case `chpasswd <<<"$user:$pass"`

Comment: Thank you so much SiegeX. I hope your new day goes well.